How to adjust the size of one subplot independently of other subplots in a matplotlib figure?
I want to have horizontally aligned 3D and 2D plots, where the y-axis of the 2D plot is the same height as the z-axis of the 3D plot. The following code produces a default output:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_size_inches(10, 4)
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5)

# 3D surface plot
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121, projection="3d")
ax1.set(zlabel="Value")

# 2D line plot
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
ax2.set(ylabel="Value")

plt.show() 


I want to shrink down the right hand side 2D subplot so that the y-axis ("Value") is a similar height to (or preferably the same height as) the z-axis ("Value") on the 3D plot (ideally I want them to line up).
I haven't been able to find a way to change subplot sizes independently like this in matplotlib (setting relative ratios and  gridspec don't seem able to achieve this).
Any help would be much appreciated.

You can use set_position() to change the dimensions of one of the subplot:
plt.figure(1).axes[1].set_position([0.6,0.4,0.25,0.3])  # left, bottom, width, height

It gives:


Thank you! This is quick and easy and gives me the exact alignment I wanted.

As the other answer said, you can use set_position() to set the position and dimensions of the subplot. But I found a way to position it such that it's aligned with z-axis line of the 3d plot as you wanted.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.transforms import Bbox

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_size_inches(10, 4)
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121, projection="3d")
ax1.set(zlabel="Value")

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
ax2.set(ylabel="Value")


bbox3d = ax1.get_position()

trans_proj = ax1.get_proj()

# Get the bounds of the z axis
zmin_3d = ax1.get_zlim()[0]
zmax_3d = ax1.get_zlim()[1]

# Transform these bounds into plot (figure) coordinates
zmin_display = ax1.transData.transform((0, zmin_3d))
zmax_display = ax1.transData.transform((0, zmax_3d))

zmin_fig = fig.transFigure.inverted().transform(zmin_display)
zmax_fig = fig.transFigure.inverted().transform(zmax_display)

bbox2d = ax2.get_position()
ax2.set_position([
    bbox2d.x0,
    zmin_fig[1], # use z-min\s y coord which corresponds to the height of the origin
    0.5, # set width and height suitably
    0.5
])

plt.show()




This is great - thank you. I was actually after the kind of alignment that the first poster gave, but this extra functionality is certainly very useful to know about.
